# Using Vector2 and Vector2 as generic constraints?

Tags: c#, generics, xna, constraints, physics

I am trying to create a somewhat generic xna physics module like this:

```
   class PhysicsModule<T> : where T : Vector2, Vector3
   {
        private List<PhysicsForce<T>> _globalForces;

        public PhysicsModule()
        {
            _globalForces = new List<PhysicsForce<T>>();
        }

         /// <summary>
        /// Updates the resultant which will be sent to be applied on all entities.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">...</param>
        public override void UpdateResultant(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            _resultant = T.Zero;
            foreach (PhysicsForce<T> force in _globalForces)
            {
                T vector = T.Multiply(force.Direction, force.Magnitude);
                T modifiedByTime = T.Multiply(vector, (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds);

                _resultant = T.Add(_resultant, modifiedByTime);

            }

        }
    }

    class PhysicsForce<T> where T : Vector2, Vector3
    {
        public T Direction;
        public float Magnitude; 
    }
```

I know this code won't work, it only serves as a sample to make clear what I want to do. 
Is this possible or will I be better of having an abstract base like this

```
class PhysicsModule2D : PhysicsModule 

class PhysicsForce2D : PhysicsForce
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to always fulfill all generic constraints
2. .net generics only allow you to call methods from the generic constraint, i.e. unlink C++ templates they don't work by name. One consequence of this is that you can't use static methods or operators on T.
3. There is a workaround using dynamic typing(either using the `dynamic` keyword in C# 4 or generating delegates on the fly as MiscUtil does). This reduces performance significantly though.
4. There is an ugly hack that allows high performance, it's a bit complicated though.
5. You can write the code with some placeholders and then use a code generator to generate the other versions
6. You can simply implement 2D and 3D separately manually. Probably the best choice even if it violates DRY.

For 4) you first create a generic interface that contains all methods on VectorX you want to use. Like this:

```
interface VectorMath
{
  T Add(T v1,T v2);
}
```

Then you implement it using `struct`s. And then you pass that struct as a second generic parameter to your class.

Comment: Thx for the great explanation! Will try 4) but like you say I will probably end up with separate implementations.